# override enum in derived class in C#

Tags: c#, enums, derived-class

I'm creating an `abstract` finite machine state class with an `enum` for the possible commands it can receive, something like:

```
public abstract class FSMBase
{
    public enum Commands {};
    public enum States;
    public Dictionary<Transition, States> AvailableTransitions;
    public States CurrentState;

    public abstract void InitCommandsAndStatesAndTransitiosnAndInitialState();

    public void ProcessCommand(Commands _command)
    {
        Transition RequestedTransition = new Transition(CurrentState, command);
        if(AvailableTransitions.TryGetValue(RequestedTransition, out State nextState) //pseudocode
        {
             CurrentState = nextState;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the derived class I would like to *override* the `States`, the `Transitions` and the `Commands`. Something like:

```
public class MyFSM : FSMBase
{
    public override void InitCommandsAndStatesAndTransitiosnAndInitialState()
    {
        States = {Off, starting, started, ...} //HERE IS MY PROBLEM
        Commands = {start, stop, finish, ...}; // HERE IS MY PROBLEM

        Transitions = new Dictionary<Transition, BaseState>
        {
            {new Transition(States.Off, Commands.Start), States.starting},
            ....
        }

        CurrentState = States.Off;
    }
}
```

How do I *override* the `enum`s in my derived class ???

Comment: I would say that `enum` is fine to implement FSM, but it has a weakness - it is limited when reusability required. Since you attempt to create generic FSM, I would recommen to use [State pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern)

Comment: hum.. I've to agree.. I want to add entering and exiting actions to my states and .. It feels like a hack in this scenario..

Comment: For such a scenario, a Dictionary<int, string> is most often more appropriate. You crate kind of a registry. You register strings, work internally with a corresponding index, and to the outside -  or for documentation, you can still use strings. You can also just use const int Off=1, const int On=2, that's extendable to MaxInt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `enum` is in fact `int` (`byte`, `short`, `long` ect.) and can't be overriden. I suggest using *generics* instead

```
public abstract class FSMBase<State, Command> 
  where State   : Enum  // : Enum wants C# 7.3+
  where Command : Enum {

  //TODO: I suggest have these fields private, or at least, protected
  public Dictionary<Transition, State> AvailableTransitions;
  public State CurrentState;

  public void ProcessCommand(Command _command) {
    ...
  }

}
```

When implementing `MyFSM` you can put required enums:

```
public class MyFSM : FSMBase<MyStates, MyCommands> {
  ...
}
```

**Edit:** in case of *lower* c# versions you can try same idea but different constraints:

```
public abstract class FSMBase<State, Command> 
  where State   : struct  
  where Command : struct {

  public State CurrentState;
  ...        

  // Instead of compile time error we are going to have runtime one,
  // if either State or Command is not enum
  static FSMBase() {
    if (!typeof(State).IsEnum)
      throw new InvalidCastException("Generic pararameter State must be enum!");
    else if (!typeof(Command).IsEnum)
      throw new InvalidCastException("Generic pararameter Command must be enum!");
  }
}

...

public class MyFSM : FSMBase<MyStates, MyCommands> {
  public override void InitCommandsAndStatesAndTransitiosnAndInitialState() {
    ...
    CurrentState = MyStates.Off;
    ... 
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: ups, looks nice but I'm constrained to 4.7.1 :(

Comment: @javirs: .Net framework version and c# language version are different things; you can well 
 have `4.7.1` platform and c# `7.3`:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version

Comment: Ups.. I really know nothing :) Anyhow, I'm constrained in both and the compiler said: Constraint cannot be special class Enum so .. I guess C# is also below 7.3

Comment: @javirs: if `c# 7.3` is not an option, you can try `: struct` constraint and `static` constructor to validate if generic types are `enum`s; please, see my edit

Comment: It does work ! : )  I created the FSMBase<StateEnum, CommandEnum> and it works exactly as I wanted :)

Comment: @javirs: I'm pleased to hear this :)